# SVN Server Migration Failed

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have migrated SVN server from Windows server 2008 to windows server 2012, SVN is online and able to access through URL, when i try to checkout the code using tortoise in my machine, it fails with error and shown error that unable to connect to a repository at url and url is from old server, and old SVN i have stopped already, is this because of caching or something else, how to figure out this.

Comment: Question title and body do not match at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repository URL your working copy is linked to is stored in the working copy's metadata and needs to be updated.  Because the repository URL changed, you need to [`relocate` your working copy](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-relocate.html). This assumes that only the root URL (and none of the paths within) has changed. You need to do this from the root of your working copy.

If you're attempting a fresh checkout with the proper URL, but getting an error back with the old URL, you've got something very weird going on.